# Kubernetes: supply parameters for docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I want to run docker containers using real-time scheduler. Is it possible to pass parameters in pod/deployment file to Kubernetes to run my containers as follows?

```
docker run -it --cpu-rt-runtime=950000 \
                  --ulimit rtprio=99 \
                  --cap-add=sys_nice \
                  debian:jessie
```

Comment: How are you running the container from kubernetes, is it a deployment/pod ?

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande I would like to specify these parameters in pod/deployment file. Then I require Kubernetes to run containers reflecting these parameters.

Comment: @VáclavStruhár
To clarify your question. You want to pass all parameter values like `--cpu-rt-runtime=950000` to pod/deployment. But it always will be the same parameter or you want to change them depends on situation?

Comment: @PjoterS The parameters should be specified in pod/deployment file and used by Kubernetes while deploying the docker containers in the working nodes. No change is required (once the container is started, we won't change it). The values may be different among containers (e.g., container 1: --cpu-rt-runtime=950000 and container 2: --cpu-rt-runtime=800000)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not all Docker command line features has relevant options in Kubernetes YAML.

While `sys_time` capability can be set using `securiyContext` in yaml, the `--cpu-rt-runtime=950000` cannot.

In the [K8s API Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#podsecuritycontext-v1-core) documentation you can find all the configuration that can be pass into container
under `PodSecurityContext v1 core`.

Another thing is that I`ve tried to run a container itself with the specs that you provided but I ran into an error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Your kernel does not support
cgroup cpu real-time runtime. See 'docker run --help'
```

This is related directly to kernel configuration named `CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED` that is missing from your kernel image. Without it the `cpu-rt-runtime` won`t be possible to set to container.

Answer (score 0):

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/

You can use config maps to declare variables.

Then mount config map to env variables. Pass env variables to docker args.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables

Create config map

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: special-config
  namespace: default
data:
  SPECIAL_LEVEL: very
  SPECIAL_TYPE: charm
```

Create POD

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
      envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: special-config
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: As I understand, this will pass the parameters into the docker container as environmental variables. However, I need the docker container to be instantiated with the parameters. (Or am I overseeing something?)

Comment: This will not init docker container with params. Wondering if CPU limits should be passed using ResourceLimits that kubernetes understands, I think real time scheduling using docker won't be helpful here

Answer (score 0):

Not all of these options are available in K8s but you can find a workaround using [Limit Ranges](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/). This is explained [here](https://devopspoints.com/kubernetes-lessons-learned-from-production.html).